# event.preventDefault() is not working in any browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following  tag created by WP Bakery's Post Masonry Grid:

```
<a href="https://www.domain.nl/some-page/" class="vc_gitem-link vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-modern vc_btn3-o-empty vc_btn3-color-grey" title="some value in the title"><span class="vc_btn3-placeholder">&nbsp;</span></a>
```

When this link is hovered an coloured overlay appears on the grid-item. On mobile this effect is not visible. What I want is when a user clicks on this link, the overlay appears before the link activates. I've tried this with the following jQuery code:

```
$('.project-item .vc_btn3-container a').click(function(event) {
        // Remember the link href
        var href = this.href;

        // Don't follow the link
        event.preventDefault();

        // Do the async thing
        overlayActive(function() {
            if($(window).width() <= 480) {
                console.log('it works');
                $(this).parent().parent().find('project-overlay-color').css('transform', 'scale(1,1)');
                // go to the link
                window.location = href;
            }
        });
    });
```

This doesn't work in any browser. Also, I cant find the "it works" in the console log. I've tried to place it around in the click function but the console log remains empty.

When I use inspector in Chrome and set it to a mobile device (like iphone X) the overlay appears before the link is activated when I click on the link. However, on my own mobile device the overlay won't appear.

How can I get the overlay to appear before the link is activated and navigates to the page?

Comment: It could be really dangerous, if you copy-paste some code from the internet you fully don't understand.

Comment: can you show your full html structure - does your selector work?

Comment: am pretty sure the CSS selector is not good

Comment: Also it seems Visual Composer so it's WP .. try `jQuery` instead of `$` it can be the issue

Comment: @Teemu I understand the code, the event.preventDefault is the only new thing for me.

Comment: @Pete This is the selector i am using
<a href="https://www.domain.nl/some-page/" class="vc_gitem-link vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-modern vc_btn3-o-empty vc_btn3-color-grey" title="some value in the title"><span class="vc_btn3-placeholder">&nbsp;</span></a>

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm using a function so I can use $ instead of jQuery. Nevertheless I've changed it but it still does not work

Comment: Yep that's exactly the same as you have put in the question and doesn't answer if your jquery selector should work

Comment: Umh ... setting `window.location` in the async function changes the location immediately, the page is never rendered with the new HTML. Preventing the default action of the a tag works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is bad `vc_btn3-container` does not exist. Try this:

JS

```
$('.vc_gitem-link').click(function(event) {
  // Remember the link href
  var href = this.href;

  // Don't follow the link
  event.preventDefault();

  // Do the async thing
  overlayActive(function() {
    if($(window).width() <= 480) {
      console.log('it works');
      $(this).parent().parent().find('project-overlay-color').css('transform', 'scale(1,1)');
      // go to the link
      window.location = href;
    }
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwmePB)